# where are device screenshots visible in Xcode6?

Tags: xcode6, screenshot

For Xcode 6, the older Xcode 4 & 5 ***Organizer*** menu item has been split up into both an Organizer and a Devices set of menu choices.

Under the Devices menu item, you'll see a list of the various devices Xcode knows about, in addition to simulators and things like that.

And a cleaner looking interface that lists device information, installed apps for each of those devices, etc.

Here's my question:

There are two bigger buttons on the new Devices page.  One is "View Device Logs" and the other is "Take Screenshot".

[image: Take Screenshot button in Devices]

If one presses the "Take Screenshot" button to take a screenshot of what's on the connected device, there's no *obvious* way to actually view that screenshot.

Does anyone know how to view the screenshots that were taken from the Xcode 6 Devices menu?  Hard to believe that's an oversight on the Dev Tool team's part.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Six minutes after asking my question I figured out the answer.  There's a tooltip that pops up when hovering over the "Take Screenshot" button.

The screenshots get saved directly to the desktop and you'll see them saved there with the filename format "`Screen Shot YYYY-MM-DD at HH.mm.ss AM/PM.png`".