# Device Screenshot location in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

Where do the screenshots taken in Xcode 6 get downloaded to?  I launch the devices window via Window > Devices. Then I select my test device and click on the `Take Screenshot` button.  I'm wondering where do the screenshots go.

Comment: Duplicate question: [I asked this same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275096/where-are-device-screenshots-visible-in-xcode6) a couple months back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [where are device screenshots visible in Xcode6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275096/where-are-device-screenshots-visible-in-xcode6)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The screenshot should be saved on the Desktop.